# Can you name this plant that likes shade on Asturias?

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image: several plants]

This was located in the [Turón valley on Mieres, Asturias, Spain](https://goo.gl/maps/BMwyfWtiSdw). Usually, I find this plant in shadowy, not too illuminated spots, although I'm not sure if that's important or simply coincidence. This picture is from yesterday 16th February 2019. The plant is lower than knee high, so let's say a maximum of 30cm tall maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found a helleborus, possibly *helleborus viridis*.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helleborus_viridis

Comment: Seeing that there's even a common name for it in Asturian (yerbunegru) I think you identified it perfectly :D Thank you